# Subquery returned more than 1 value. Not permitted when subquery follows =, but no subquery being used?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, union

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM [Analytics].[KE30].[View_NewKE30]
 WHERE [ReportDate] = '2018-05-31'
```

This returns the error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

However, there is no subquery being used here? It's a simple statement.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 *
FROM [Analytics].[KE30].[View_NewKE30]
WHERE [ReportDate] = '2017-08-31'
```

It works, and returns a set of records.

`[KE30].[View_NewKE30]` is a view which UNION joins two tables. `[ReportDate]` is a datetime field which exists in these two tables. '2018-05-31' belongs to one of the table, '2017-08-31' belongs to the other.

EDIT: Here is the View_NewKE30

```
CREATE VIEW [KE30].[View_NewKE30]
AS
(SELECT 
[ReportDate]
FROM [KE30].[TableA])
UNION ALL
(SELECT
[ReportDate]
FROM [KE30].[TableB])
```

Comment: can you show View_NewKE30 ?

Comment: You problem is in your View not in your query.

Comment: Without source of view it is difficult to help.

Comment: added the code for View_NewKE30

Comment: Are you sure it is the actual code in the view, you might have a sub query in that or try to aggregate union all into one query that will help

Comment: There are other fields in both tables but I don't think they are relevant to this problem, would they?

Comment: SQL Server (I presume that's your product, if so please tag [tag:sql-server], if not please add an appropriate tag) doesn't tend to *lie* in its error messages. If it's complaining about a subquery, it really does mean there's a problem with a subquery. If you're not finding a subquery in the code you're looking at, you're not looking at the code it's complaining about.

Comment: Try altering the view without the parenthesis around the select statements. Which database are you using?

Comment: Also, are you just trying to return distinct dates?In which case do a UNION not a UNION ALL